# Why does a Ubuntu Linux Mono-.NET 4.5 C# Program GP Fault upon loading and running a Shared Object?

Tags: ubuntu, c++, shared-library, c#

On my Ubuntu Linux 15.10 Lenovo desktop computer, I wrote a Mono-.NET 4.5 C# program with a BuildIPCameraListLinux.config file  which uses DLLImport to load libxmlconverter.so. Only upon point and click, after libxmlconverter.so executes realpath it throws a general protection fault. 
  The purpose of libxmlconverter.so is read a C++ Header file with a huge array of camera vendors and products. libxmlconverter.so transform this huge C++ array into an XML document using TinyXML.
  The purpose of the Mono-NET 4.5 C# program is to parse the XML document and store into a MYSQL 5.6 database. I am aware there are 2 generations of MYSQL.Data.DLL , one for Mono-.NET 3.5 and one for Mono-NET 4.5.
  What might cause this GPFault and how to fix it?

Comment: The GP fault is likely caused by the interaction between the C function realpath and the mono environment.

Comment: Is readlink the only reliable solution? Thank you.

Comment: 1. When I run mono ./BuildIPCameraListLinux.exe everything still works when I use readlink.
2. Is the problem in BuildIPCameraListLinux.config file contents?